# Connecting with database (MySQL) on my own server SWIFT 2

Tags: ios, mysql, database, swift, swift2

I would like to ask you, if you have any idea how can I connect my application (Swift 2, iOS 9) to my own MySQL data base? I would like to input new entities, delete it and update it. I would like to create a login and a registration field, to my app and I need simple explanation, how can I send data from my app to serwer.

Registration form include:

- nick
- email
- password
- confirm password

Login form include:

- nick/email
- password

For any hints thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not recommended to do direct connections to the db from an application, what you can do instead is compile info on db to JSON using a .PHP script and then parse the info on Swift with swiftyjson.

To update it, again you do it with a .PHP script where you use $GET to get the data sent from Swift via HTTPRequest.

Regards!

Comment: Follow this tutorial to add users into the database. I'm not certain as to remove/update users. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9sfrXvZq-Y